# Add comma separator between two strings which are in specific format

Tags: java, regex

Have two strings in specific format.Need to add comma between two strings using regex.

```
   String input1 = "\"abc_xyz\"";
   String input2 = "\"ijk_bcd\"";
   String result = (input1+input2).replaceAll("([^ ]) ", "$1,");
```

With the above regex I am getting result as

```
"abc_xyz" "ijk_bcd". 
Expected output should look like 
"abc_xyz","ijk_bcd".
```

Comment: What about `String result = (input1+ "," +input2);` ?

Comment: Impossible, [you get](https://ideone.com/EQl0Fv) `"abc_xyz""ijk_bcd"`, not `"abc_xyz" "ijk_bcd"`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression might also solve the problem, yet it is unnecessary:

```
(.*")(".*)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VK7Fbr/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(.*\")(\".*)";
final String string = input1+input2;
final String subst = "$1,$2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
String joinedString = String.join(",", input1, input2);
```